# Android updating android.support.v4.content to androidx.core.content.FileProvider does not stay

Tags: android, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, androidx, android-fileprovider

I am trying to update the FileProvider class from `android.support.v4.content.FileProvider` to `androidx.core.content.FileProvider` which allows me to build successfully.

When I run `ionic cap sync` it reverts back to `android.support.v4.content.FileProvider`...

I have `cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter` installed.

How can I make it stay as `androidx.core.content.FileProvider` or make the adapter work?

In my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
</provider>
```

Comment: You can try with jetifier: `npm install jetifier --save` `npx jetify` `npx cap sync android`

Comment: @MishaMashina That worked, can you provide an answer so that I can accept it? Also, am I good to remove the `cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter`?

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but no need for an official answer - this issue happens regularly and is already well answered and commented on many questions here :) And you should keep the `cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter` too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migrating a Cordova Android project to AndroidX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59429175/migrating-a-cordova-android-project-to-androidx)

Answer (score 1):

The above comment from @MishaMashina is the definitive answer. I am only answering here as I was able to get my project to compile running jetify without using the cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter.